# SWIFT UI, when the content of one of my views updates from current view, the current view exits by itself

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a chat in which there are 4 views.

1. Settings view
2. Recent Messages view, where you can see the last message you have received/sent
3. Contacts view where you just see the contacts you have
4. Chat log view

When I send message in chat log view, the content in Recent Messages is updated, because the last message is changed, when updating my chat log view exits to main view

Here is my Views:
the main view with tab bar from where 3 other views is accessed
Messages view: where the last messages is shown
Chat Log view

the chat log view exits when I do handleSend function in ChatLogViewModel

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var         vm          = MainMessagesViewModel()          //view model variable
    @State       private var isPresented = false                            //bool variable to show/hide login view
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: .constant(0)) {
                ContactsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("მეგობრები", systemImage: "person.2")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                
                
                MessagesView().environmentObject(vm)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("ჩატები", systemImage: "message")
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                 
                
                SettingsView().environmentObject(vm)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("დაყენებები", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: nil){    //iOS 16 style to call a view with @published variable (@state needed)
                LogInView(didCompleteLogin: {
                    self.vm.isCurrentlyLogOut = false
                    self.vm.fetchCurrentUser()
                })
            }
            .onReceive(vm.$isCurrentlyLogOut) { isCurrentlyLogOut in
                self.isPresented = isCurrentlyLogOut
                self.vm.fetchCurrentUser()
            }
            .onChange(of: isPresented) { isCurrentlyLogOut in
                self.vm.isCurrentlyLogOut = isCurrentlyLogOut
                self.vm.fetchCurrentUser()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainMessagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user              : User?                                                                //current user (optional because is nil on start)
    @Published var isCurrentlyLogOut = false
    @Published var recentMessages    = [RecentMessage]()                                                    //array containing recent messages user has sent
    private    var firestoreListener : ListenerRegistration?

    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isCurrentlyLogOut = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid == nil                    //figure out if there is no user logged in
        }
        fetchCurrentUser()                                                                                  //fetch a logged in user
        fetchRecentMessages()
    }
    
    
    func fetchCurrentUser() {                                                                              //fetching the user variable inside vm
        
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }                       //if there is a uid available create uid variable
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, err in  //retrieve from users/uid/ user's data, which is stored in snapshot
            if let err = err {                                                                             //error handler
                print("Failed to fetch current user: ", err)
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else { return }                                               //create a data variable if there is a data in snapshot
            self.user = .init(data: data)                                                                   //vm's user is initialized with struct's init()
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchRecentMessages() {
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("recent_messages")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("messages")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, err in
                    
                if let err = err {
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
                
                querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                    
                    let docId = change.document.documentID
                    let data  = change.document.data()
                    if let index = self.recentMessages.firstIndex(where: {rm in
                        return rm.documentId == docId
                    }) {
                        self.recentMessages.remove(at: index)
                    }
                    self.recentMessages.insert(.init(documentId: docId, data: data), at: 0)
                    
                })
                
            }
    }
}
```

```
//MARK: - CHAT LOG VIEW

struct ChatLogView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ChatLogViewModel            //view model variable
    
    let interlocutor: User?                             //variable for interlocutor (provided from main view)
    
    init(interlocutor: User?) {                         //initialize interlocutor
        self.interlocutor = interlocutor
        self.vm = .init(interlocutor: interlocutor)     //initialize view model using interlocutor
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            messagesView
        }
        .navigationTitle(interlocutor?.email ?? "")
    }
    
    //MARK: - MESSAGES VIEW
    private var messagesView: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                VStack {
                    ForEach(vm.chatMessages) { message in
                        VStack {
                            if message.fromId == FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid{
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(message.text)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    }
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                                    .background(Color.blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(25)
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            } else {
                                HStack {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(message.text)
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    }
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                                    .background(Color(.init(white: 0.94, alpha: 1)))
                                    .cornerRadius(25)
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .id("empty")
                }
                .onReceive(vm.$count) { _ in                                    //when count of messages changes
                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {                    //perform animation to scroll to the bottom of view
                        scrollViewProxy.scrollTo("empty", anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {                                         //insert a view to the bottom
            chatBottomBar
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - CHAT BOTTOM BAR VIEW
    
    private var chatBottomBar: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "paperclip")
                .padding(.leading, 5)
            
            TextField("Message", text: $vm.chatText)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(25)
            
            Button {
                vm.handleSend()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        .padding(.vertical, 7)
        .background(Color(.init(white: 0.95, alpha: 0.99)))
    }
}
```

```
class ChatLogViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let interlocutor : User?                            //user whom you send a message
    @Published var chatText     = ""                    //var for a text of message
    @Published var chatMessages = [ChatMessage]()       //array of messages
    @Published var count        = 0                     //var to track when a message is added to scroll down
    
    
    init (interlocutor : User?) {
        self.interlocutor  = interlocutor               //init a interlocutor using a interlocutor from contacts view
        fetchMessages()                                 //fetch messages from firestore to the app
    }
    
    func fetchMessages() {
        guard let fromId = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}       //create a fromID using current user's if available
        guard let toId   = interlocutor?.uid else {return}                                  //create a toID using interlocutor's id
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("messages")                             //retrieve message data from path /messages/fromId/toId/ (ordered by time)
            .document(fromId)
            .collection(toId)
            .order(by: "timestamp")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, err in                                    //continiously listen to selected folder, the data will be in querySnapshot
                
                if let err = err {                                                          //error handler
                    print("Failed to listen messages: ", err)
                }
                
                querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in                          //if there is a change of documents in querySnapshot
                    if change.type == .added {
                        let data = change.document.data()                                   //create data variable
                        let docId = change.document.documentID                              //create docId variable
                        let chatMessage = ChatMessage(documentId: docId, data: data)        //create chatMessage variable (initilize it with stucts's init using docId and data)
                        self.chatMessages.append(chatMessage)                               //add a message to messages array
                    }
                })
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {                                                  //if message is added increase messages count (for scroll to bottom)
                    self.count += 1
                }
                
            }
    }
    
    func handleSend() {                                                                             //function to send a message
        guard let fromId = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}               //if there is current user's id store it in fromId
        guard let toId   = interlocutor?.uid else {return}                                          //if there is interculor store their uid in toId
        
        let document = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("messages")                      //create a message document |FOR SENDER| in message/fromId/toId/
            .document(fromId)
            .collection(toId)
            .document()
        
        let messageData = [                                                                         //create a message data variable
            
            "fromId"    : fromId,
            "toId"      : toId,
            "text"      : chatText,
            "timestamp" : Timestamp()
            
        ] as [String : Any]
        
        document.setData(messageData) { err in                                                      //for the document created set data using created messageData
            
            if let err = err {                                                                      //error handler
                print("Failed to send a message: ", err)
                return
            }
            
            self.persistRecentMessage()
            
            self.chatText = ""                                                                      //when the handleSend() is called clean chatText variable as so textFiled
            self.count += 1                                                                         //increase message count (for scroll down)
        }
        
        let recepientMessageDocument = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("messages")      //create a message document |FOR RECEPINT| in messages/toId/fromId/
            .document(toId)
            .collection(fromId)
            .document()
            
        recepientMessageDocument.setData(messageData) { err in                                      //for the document created set data using created messageData
            if let err = err {                                                                      //don't have to create another message data because it is the same
                print("Failed to send a message: ", err)
                return
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private func persistRecentMessage() {
        
        guard let uid  = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}                 //create uid if uid of current user is available
        guard let toId = interlocutor?.uid else {return}
        
        let document = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("recent_messages")               //create document to store the message to /recent_messages/uid/messages/toId
            .document(uid)
            .collection("messages")
            .document(toId)
        
        let data = [                                                                                //recent message data variable
            "timestamp"    : Timestamp(),
            "text"         : self.chatText,
            "formId"       : uid,
            "toId"         : toId,
            "profilePicURL": interlocutor?.profilePictureUrl ?? "",
            "email"        : interlocutor?.email ?? ""
        ] as [String : Any]
        
        
        document.setData(data) { err in                                                             //set recent message to created document
            if let err = err {
                print("Faild to store recent message: ", err)
                return
            }

        }
        

                
        let recepientData = [                                                                                //recent message data variable
            "timestamp"    : Timestamp(),
            "text"         : self.chatText,
            "formId"       : uid,
            "toId"         : toId,
            "profilePicURL": "",
            "email"        : ""
        ] as [String : Any]
        
        let recepientRecentMessageDocument = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("recent_messages")                                                                 //create a recent message document |FOR RECEPINT| in /recent_messages/toId/messages/uid
            .document(toId)
            .collection("messages")
            .document(uid)
            
        recepientRecentMessageDocument.setData(data) { err in                                       //for the document created set data using created messageData
            if let err = err {                                                                      //dont have to create another message data because it is the same
                print("Failed to send a message: ", err)
                return
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
struct MessagesView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var vm : MainMessagesViewModel
    
    var body: some View{

            ScrollView {
                ForEach (vm.recentMessages) { recentMessage in
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("")
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                WebImage(url: URL(string:recentMessage.profilePictureUrl))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(recentMessage.email)
                                    Text(recentMessage.text)
                                }
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                Text("date")
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("მეგობრები"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
}
```

I need to chat log view do not exit when updating contents in messages view.

When I commented out `self.persistRecentMessage()` from `func handleSend()` function in `ChatLogViewModel`, disabling in this way updating of contents in Messages View, ChatLogView stopped exiting

Comment: In your `MainView`, you set the Tab View with a constant `selection` value. That means any time MainView gets reappraised by SwiftUI's drawing system it’s going to change your tabs – and that can happen at times that make it look like something else is a cause. Try removing that, and fi the issue still exists it’ll make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: @ScottM I have deleted it. Nothing changed. By the way, when the messages view is updating while i am on another view other that chat log view (on contacts view, messages view, settings view, or empty text view where I navigate from messages view) nothing hapens. The empty text view does not exit as chatlogview do.